# Bulgaria, is freecamping allowed in the Pirin mountains park?

Tags: camping, bulgaria

In the Pirin mountains in Bulgaria there is a trail along the ridges of the highest mountains, I would like to follow it, but I would like to keep my plan flexible in case I saw some scenic spots and side trails I would like to see. There are a lot of mountain refuges in the area. But I suspect that in the Summer season it would be difficult to find a place for a traveller with no plans and the idea to choose the direction of the trail on the spot.

Is it allowed to place a tent on a spot along the trail? Alternatively, are there camping places with a lot of space near the refuges?